# SQL Server Error: A MERGE statement must be terminated by a semi-colon (;)

Tags: sql-server, merge

I have the following on a SQL Server 2014 database:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.AssetGroupClassification  ( 
    ClassificationId    int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ClassificationName  varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AssetGroupClassification.ClassificationId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(ClassificationId)
)
GO
CREATE TYPE dbo.AssetGroupClassUDT AS TABLE (
    ClassificationId int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL, 
    ClassificationName varchar(25) NOT NULL
    )
GO
```

I'm attempting to create the below Stored Proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.AssetGroupClassUpsert
        @assetGrpClassData AssetGroupClassUDT READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION agcUpsertTran

        MERGE AssetGroupClassification AS t
        USING @assetGrpClassData AS src
        ON t.ClassificationId = src.ClassificationId
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET ClassificationName = src.ClassificationName
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT (ClassificationName)
            VALUES (src.ClassificationName);

        COMMIT TRANSACTION agcUpsertTran
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@trancount > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        DECLARE @errMsg nvarchar(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        RAISERROR (@errMsg, 16, 1)

        RETURN 99   
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

However, I receive the error:

```
 A MERGE statement must be terminated by a semi-colon (;).
```

What am I missing? The semi-colon is clearly there so there must be something else up.

Comment: `Command(s) completed successfully.`

Comment: I can run your scripts without a problem. Are you running it as part of a larger script?

Comment: @ Devart, thanks, that's interesting

Comment: @GarethD nope, the only other bits in the script are a check before (to drop the proc if it exists) and then to add permissions for it. FYI, the Compatibility level is set to 120

Comment: You start a transactio *inside* `TRY` but try to rollback in the `CATCH` clause? Why not start it outside? BTW, what did you do to get this error? Did you get it when executing CREATE PROCEDURE or when calling the stored procedure?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I get this error when attempting to create the procedure

Comment: I've just ran the exact same script in Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2013 and the stored proc was created. Issue to do with the IDE I'm using? (Aqua Data Studio 15.0.11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the same script in Server Explorer within Visual Studio 2013 and the stored proc was created without any problems. I assume the issue is to do with the IDE I'm using, Aqua Data Studio 15.0.11.

Comment: Same here: on DBeaver I got error, went to Management Studio and worked.

Comment: I am facing this problem in SQL Server Manage Studio v17.7. hmm

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking all SQL statements should be terminated with a semicolon.  i.e.

```
SELECT
    Example
FROM
    Test1
;

SELECT
    Example
FROM
    Test2
;
```

In practice SQL Server only enforces this for certain query types, for now.  Statements that precede CTEs and MERGEs are an example of this.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx):

> ; Transact-SQL statement terminator.Although the semicolon is not
>   required for most statements in this version of SQL Server, it will be
>   required in a future version.

Of course it doesn't help that the error message tells you to terminate the merge but doesn't mention the preceding query is also required.   Try:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION agcUpsertTran;

    MERGE AssetGroupClassification AS t
    ....
    ;
```

Comment: The script is OK. BEGIN TRAN doesn't require a semicolon.

Comment: Good point.  Tested with and without.  It made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the syntax below from [Simple-talk](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/)

```
MERGE BookInventory bi

USING BookOrder bo

ON bi.TitleID = bo.TitleID

WHEN MATCHED AND

  bi.Quantity + bo.Quantity = 0 THEN

  DELETE

WHEN MATCHED THEN

  UPDATE

  SET bi.Quantity = bi.Quantity + bo.Quantity

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN

  INSERT (TitleID, Title, Quantity)

  VALUES (bo.TitleID, bo.Title,bo.Quantity)

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE

  AND bi.Quantity = 0 THEN

  DELETE;
```

I think, you are missing,

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
```

Comment: `BY TARGET` is optional, something that *is* mentioned in the blog post. In any way, syntax should be checked against [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just as a side node. If you're using `Visual Studio Code` with the MSSQL Plugin `SQL Server (mssql)`, you will have the same problem. Even though the syntax is correct, on execution it complains about the missing semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

When you are executing your script under the visual studio editor in script file,  at end of the script you need to add `;` after adding the semicolon VS will build the script successfully